# Loading native lib error

Tags: java, native, lib

I have problem with starting my app on linux, from IDE and direct from win everthink is ok, but on linux I'm getting following error:

```
native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
mar 06, 2017 7:54:44 PM org.jnativehook.DefaultLibraryLocator getLibraries
SEVERE: Unable to extract the native library /org/jnativehook/lib/linux/arm/libJNativeHook.so!

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.getAutoRepeatRate()Ljava/lang/Integer;
at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.getAutoRepeatRate(Native Method)
at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at the.main.pac.TheModbusSimpleTesterWindow$1.run(TheModbusSimpleTesterWindow.java:74)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Is the library for the correct processor architecture?

Comment: Did you try if it works with JNativeHook 2.1.0? 2.2pre2 looks like a pre-release version, which might contain bugs and which should be reported against JNativeHook.

Comment: "2.2pre2" concerns other lib which I'm using -  "rxtx"

Comment: I'm not sure if architecture is supported - I'm trying to launch it on RPi3

Answer (score 0):

The library tries to extract the naive code from the Jar if no library is found on the [java.library.path](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/) property.  If you are repacking the Jar, you must pack the libraries to the same location within the Jar **and fully comply with the GPL licence for your project.**  The library must be included as a stand-alone library to comply with the Lesser-GPL.  You can specify a different library loading method or location by implementing the [NativeLibraryLocator](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/2.1/src/java/org/jnativehook/NativeLibraryLocator.java) interface.  See [DefaultLibraryLocator](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/2.1/src/java/org/jnativehook/DefaultLibraryLocator.java) for an implementation example.